# R - Cut and Break usage on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

[image]

- Need to assign grouping to the entity column based on col1, col2, and col3; hence add three new columns, Group_col1, Group_col2, Group_col3
- the number of groups is fixed and equals to 6 (5,4,3,2,1,0)
- For each col1/col2/col3 , below calc is required to label the groups:

  a. find **min, max, and the mid value of the column**

  b. assign entity to the **label '0'** if the **col value > mid value**

  c. split the remaining col values into 5 groups and assign the group labels as 5,4,3,2,1
  depending upon the col values < mid value ; entity belongs to group 5 if the col values are lowest values and so on.

`dput`:

```
structure(list(entity = c("a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", 
"k", "l", "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b"
), col1 = c(18, 27, 28, 50, 42, 18, 18, 39, 16, 49, 42, 26, 18, 
38, 15, 50, 18, 10, 36, 22), col2 = c(110, 111, 159, 128, 113, 
123, 128, 122, 167, 167, 113, 185, 129, 104, 180, 123, 152, 111, 
117, 115), col3 = c(85, 69, 64, 96, 55, 99, 73, 55, 50, 62, 66, 
87, 77, 77, 53, 60, 96, 82, 100, 55)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Result after running the code snippet:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'col', create an index to subset the values that are less than or equal to the `median` value ('i1'), use that subset to get the difference from the `min`imum value, apply `cut` while specifying `breaks` as 5, and `replace` the negated (`i1` - greater than median value) to 0

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 df1  %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('col'),
   ~ {i1 <- .x <= median(.x)
    replace(replace(rep(NA_real_, n()), i1,
   as.integer(cut(-abs(.x[i1] - min(.x, na.rm = TRUE)), 5))),
      !i1 ,0 )},
   .names = "Group_{.col}"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 × 7
   entity  col1  col2  col3 Group_col1 Group_col2 Group_col3
   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 a         18   110    85          3          4          0
 2 s         27   111    69          0          4          1
 3 d         28   159    64          0          0          2
 4 f         50   128    96          0          0          0
 5 g         42   113    55          0          3          4
 6 h         18   123    99          3          1          0
 7 j         18   128    73          3          0          0
 8 k         39   122    55          0          1          4
 9 l         16   167    50          4          0          5
10 q         49   167    62          0          0          2
11 w         42   113    66          0          3          1
12 e         26   185    87          1          0          0
13 r         18   129    77          3          0          0
14 t         38   104    77          0          5          0
15 y         15   180    53          4          0          5
16 z         50   123    60          0          1          3
17 x         18   152    96          3          0          0
18 c         10   111    82          5          4          0
19 v         36   117   100          0          2          0
20 b         22   115    55          2          3          4
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, the results from the above snippet are slighty different than expected. I have pasted the image after running the code. Notice, the check_col1.. Any value that's greater than the mid value of col1, should be labeled as group '0'..and the remaining values must be grouped under 5,4,3,2,1 depending upon how close they are to min value...

Comment: @CodeMaster when you say close to min value, is it based on the difference from the `min` value, i.e. absolute difference in ascending order? as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ie, largest difference as 5

Comment: @CodeMaster I updated the post based on your comments.  Here, the groups are based calculated based on the absolute difference of values that are less thatn median with the min value (applied `cut`) on it and the values greater from median are 0

Comment: hmm. the mid value for the col1 = (min+max)/2  = 30.. that means any number in col1>30, should be flagged as group 0..  from the updated snippet, it flags 0 even for the values 27,28...

Comment: @CodeMaster i get `median(df1$col1)#
[1] 26.5`, thus 27, 28 are 0

Comment: oh, it is based on the median value. then the grouping is correct..

Comment: @CodeMaster Depends on how you are describing the `mid value`.  `(min(df1$col1) + max(df1$col1))/2@
[1] 30`.  You can check `fivenum(df1$col1)#
[1] 10.0 18.0 26.5 40.5 50.0`